# Extract Binary Data from SQL Server using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, binaryfiles

I have a database to which I upload files (such as PDFs, images, etc). I save these to the database as Varbinary (max).

I upload these files using C# MVC. What I was wondering is how can I view these files using a T-SQL query, not .net.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly.

Why don't you write a simple viewer application?

There are free and commercial ones out there. I haven't used this one, but it does have a trial version: [SQL Image Viewer](http://www.sqlimageviewer.com/)

Comment: Yes, I am going to over the next couple of days, I just wanted a quick way to verify that the file was being uploaded correctly. Currently in my database, the binary data is showing as "0x00000000......" which doesn't seem right to me. I guess I'll be working on the viewer sooner than expected!

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to extract the files in order to view them.

SQL Server and SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) don't have a facility to view binary data in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sp_OAxxxx functions (the COM interaction functions) to create the appropriate viewers, but ultimately these viewer will require the data written to disk.